# How can I find documents accessed to answer my Xquery query?

Tags: xquery

I have the following objective. I want to find, which documents contain my data when executing any kind of Xquery or XPath. In other words, I need every document that is providing me the result data for a given query. I try to do this in eXist-db environment, but I suppose there should be something on Xquery level.

I found op:context-document() operator which seems to have functionality I want, yet, as an operator it is not available for me. fn:document-uri also does not do the trick, as its $arg must be a document node, otherwise it returns an empty sequence.

Do you have any idea in mind? All the assistance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fn:base-uri()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-base-uri) may help; it returns the base URI property of a node:

```
for $d in doc('....')/your[query]
return base-uri($d)
```

You can also use it to filter your documents for specific types:

```
collection('/path/to/documents')[ends-with(base-uri(), '.xml')]
```

Comment: Technically though, the base URI of a node is dependent on the value of `xml:base` attributes as well though so isn't necessarily exactly what you want.  I'd go for `for $d in (your query)/ancestor-or-self::document-node() return document-uri($d)` which will return the list of all the documents in the result.

Comment: Thank you, Oliver. I will have a closer look this evening after I conquer exist's triggers. :) Once again, highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard XPath / XQuery function **[`collection()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-collection)** .

**For example**, using Saxon:

```
collection('file:///a/b/c/d?select=*.xml')[yourBooleanExpression]
```

selects the document nodes of all XML documents, residing in the `/a/b/c/d` directory of the filesystem, that satisfy your criteria (`yourBooleanExpression` evaluates to `true()`)